# Haiku - change username from 'user' to something else?

Tags: ssh, user-accounts, users, haiku

Is it possible to change the default username in Haiku from `user` to something else?

When setting-up pre-shared keys between my Haiku workstation and remote devices, it would be nice to be able to type `ssh host.tld` rather than `ssh remoteuser@host.tld`.

The default username in Haiku is `user` (which makes sense since it's designed to be a single-user OS), but altering that when starting remote sessions would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the only way to do this at this point is to manually edit /etc/passwd.

Answer (score 2):

Ssh has a config file located at `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host computer host.tld
Hostname host.tld¬
User remote
Compression yes¬
Port 22
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pkey¬
```

With this kind of config you can do

```
ssh computer
```

And it will connect to `host.tld` with username `remote` on port `22` with compression and the given identity file.

See ssh man for more information.

Answer (score 2):

When you build your own images, you can also specify the user name in your UserBuildConfig file (see build/jam/UserBuildConfig.sample/.ReadMe):

```
HAIKU_ROOT_USER_NAME = notuser ;
HAIKU_ROOT_USER_REAL_NAME = "Your Name" ;
```